# ¿Detectar click solo dentro de los elementos de una imagen PNG en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Bueno lo que quiero es saber si existe una función donde detecte el click en la imagen mas no en el vació(en la transparencia), por ejemplo en el framework phaser hay una función donde se realiza esto la cual es esta

```
 var image= game.add.sprite(500, 220, 'image');

    image.inputEnabled = true;
    image.input.pixelPerfectClick = true;
    image.events.onInputDown.add( function(){
        console.log("SE DIO CLICK EN ELLA");
    }, this);
```

Hay algún metodo el cual pueda realizar esto sin usar frameworks?

Comment: Creo que se podría hacer sin framework, usando canvas y detectando el pixel que se pulsó y su alpha. Ando algo liado ahora mismo, lo intentaré luego y te pongo una respuesta si nadie te la ha dado ya.

Comment: utiliza la etiqueta `<img>` con el atributo `usemap` asociada a un `<map>` donde definas las coordenadas de tu imagen (evitando la transparencia) y asignalo a un evento `onClick`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podrias utilizar `<map></map>` dentro de una imagen para detectar el área en donde se da click dentro, por ejemplo:

```html
<p>Click en la computadora, el teléfono, o en el café para ver que sucede:</p>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" width="400" height="379">

<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" onclick="alert('click en computadora')">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" onclick="alert('click en el teléfono')">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" onclick="alert('click en el café')">
</map>
```

Más información: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp

Comment: Me parece buena opción esta pero como podre calcular las coordenadas de un triangulo.

Answer (score 0):

Una tecnica es usar un [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) para pintar la imagen. La restricción es que la imagen debe de ser local o en su caso codificada en [base64](/questions/tagged/base64).

Mediante el metodo `canvas.getImageData` se obtienen los valores del pixel.
puedes leer mas de este metodo [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
};
image.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";

function findPos(obj) {
  var current_left = 0,
    current_top = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      current_left += obj.offsetLeft;
      current_top += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return {
      x: current_left,
      y: current_top
    };
  }
  return undefined;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
    throw "Invalid color component";
  return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}

$('#myCanvas').click(function(e) {
  var position = findPos(this);
  var x = e.pageX - position.x;
  var y = e.pageY - position.y;
  var coordinate = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
  var canvas = this.getContext('2d');
  var p = canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
  var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
  console.log("HEX: " + hex);
  console.log("transparencia:" + p[3]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
  Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
```